# Secured Elastic Search R connection Error - Client requested protocal TLSv1 not enabled or not supported

Tags: r, elasticsearch, configuration, openssl, ropensci

I use the `elastic 0.7.8` R package to connect to my `Elastic Search` instance.
Recently, I tried to secure the Elastic Search by using `Search Guard 2`.

Everything work fines after securing it. 
But when I try to connect from R, it fails.

```
library(elastic)
connect(es_base = "https://localhost", es_port = 9200, es_user = USER, es_pwd = PASS)
```

The error in the log is **"Client requested protocal TLSv1 not enabled or not supported"**

I tried to connect to Elastic Search using cURL as below:

- curl -k --tlsv1.1 -u USER:PASS https://localhost:9200 (This works)
- curl -k --tlsv1.0 -u USER:PASS https://localhost:9200 (This fails)

I am unable to figure out how to force R to use TLSv1.1.

Please assist.

Below are the version:

- R : 3.3.1
- Elastic Search: 2.4.1
- GCC: 4.9.2
- OS: RHEL 6.7
- Openssl: 1.0.1.e-fips 11 Feb 2013

Comment: i think you misspelled `elasic` and you didn't include the R code you're using for the connection.

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr. I have corrected it.

Comment: What version of `elastic`? And link to Search Guard ?  I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: @sckott I have updated the version. I also accepted the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In elasticsearch.yml simply set

```
searchguard.ssl.http.enabled_protocols:
  - "TLSv1.2"
  - "TLSv1.1"
  - "TLSv1"
```

See also https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard-ssl/blob/master/searchguard-ssl-config-template.yml

Comment: Thanks @Search Guard for the quick reply.